# Spring Data Rest: how to save a property that is an array of another entity?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I'm trying to send a POST request to save an entity in a Spring Data Rest repository.

The save is OK, but only for simple properties like Strings, etc...

But when I have to save a complex property (like a List<OtherEntity> otherEntities), the related object is not linked in the resource.

I'm trying to send a JSON in this format:

```
{
    "property": "value",
    "otherEntities" : "http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/otherEntities/1"
}
```

The object it's saved, but the link:

http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/objects/1/otherEntities

returns an empty array of "otherEntities" instead of the object reacheable at the url:

http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/otherEntities/1

Any idea it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to POST to a List property you have to surround it with []. So the JSON format would have to be:

```
{
    "property": "value",
    "otherEntities" : ["http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/otherEntities/1"]
}
```

Secondly, I suppose you are using @OneToMany or @ManyToMany relation. These annotations have a property "mappedBy" in one of the relation sides. Note that you can only save the relation from the side which not contains the property "mappedBy". If you save the relation from the other side, this would not be saved.